# Google Cloud Load Balancer

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I created a java app and I deployed into a Google Cloud Compute Engine, then I created a Load Balancer, but when I try to access to Load Balancer Frontend IP with port 443 it redirect to port 80

Comment: Please provide the definition of how you configured your Load Balancer.  The load balancer can be configured in a number of ways.  One way is that the Load Balancer terminates the SSL connection from the Internet and then forwards the request using HTTP (instead of HTTPS) with the assumption that the Google Internal network is trusted and doesn't need a second SSL encryption.  This is configurable ... but you should ask if you need TWO SSL encryptions and not trust the Google internal link between your LB and targets.

Comment: How can I configure for accept incoming ssl connection and then forwards the request to port 9095?

Comment: GCP provides a variety of flavors of load balancer.  If you could describe in detail which load balancer flavor you are using and it's specific configuration, that would help.  See ... https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview

Comment: I have an app inside a Compute Engine listening on port 8080, I created a `machine group`, a `backend service`, a `load balancer` and so on. When I go to load balancer `front end` ip, it point to port 80 on `Compute Engine`. How can I set forwarding to port 8080?

Answer (score 0):

You can create forwarding rules that reference an IP address and port(s) on which Load balancer accepts traffic. Here are the conceps for forwarding rules [1](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts#port_specifications). 
IP address specification [2](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts#ip_address_specifications)
To add a forwarding rule, please follow the steps here [3](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/using-forwarding-rules#adding-fr)